# C++ initalization of nested 2d array of structs

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct

In C/C++ I want to operate on a nested 2d array of structs, but fail to initalize it correctly.  The pointer in the struct meta should point to a 2d array of structs and thus nest a 2d array of structs wthin a struct. This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>


struct tabparams
{
    size_t numrows{ 1 };
    size_t numcols{ 1 };
};

struct meta
{
    std::string content{};
    meta **p { nullptr };
    tabparams parameter;
};

void Print(meta **a, tabparams par)
{
    for (size_t rowindex = 0; rowindex < par.numrows; rowindex++)
    {
        for (size_t columnindex = 0; columnindex < par.numcols; columnindex++)
        {
            if (a[rowindex][columnindex].p == nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << a[rowindex][columnindex].content << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                Print(a[rowindex][columnindex].p, a[rowindex][columnindex].parameter);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    tabparams nestedarrayparams;
    nestedarrayparams.numcols = 2;
    nestedarrayparams.numrows = 1;

    meta nestedarray[2][2] = {
        {{"nestedfoo1",nullptr, NULL},{"nestedbaz1", nullptr, NULL}},
        {{"nestedfoo2",nullptr, NULL},{"nestedbaz2", nullptr, NULL}}
    };

    tabparams rootarrayparams;

    rootarrayparams.numcols = 2;
    rootarrayparams.numrows = 1;

    meta rootarray[2][2] = {
        {{"foo1",nullptr, NULL} , {"baz", nullptr, NULL} } ,
        { {"",nullptr, NULL }, {"", nestedarray, nestedarrayparams}}
    };
}
```

The errors I get get are `Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'meta [2][2]' to 'meta **'` and `Error (active) E0144   a value of type "meta (*)[2]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "meta **"`

Do I have to change the declaration of the pointer in the struct meta?
How the nestedarray is to be referenced in the root array?

The PrintFunction should print the content field of roorarray and nestedarray?
What would be the syntax to call the Print function within main?

Comment: (1) There is no such thing as C/C++. Pick a language and stick to it. (2) This has nothing to do with nesting of anything. `meta[2][2]` and `meta**` are two completely different, incompatible types.

Comment: `T[N]` converts to `T*`, but this does not mean that `T[N][N]` converts to `T**` (but it will convert to  `T(*)[N]`)

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector<std::vector<whatever>>` instead of C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this - trying to stick with your 2D array you can simply pass a pointer to the first element (instead of a pointer to a pointer), followed by the size of the array. Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/fc8P16heE

But I really think you would be better off with some sort of STL like std::array if this is fixed size:

```cpp
    // alias the type for ease
    using metaarray = std::array<std::array<meta,2>,2>;
    // Note: array initialiser needs double brackets to init the array within the std::array - bit of an odd STL
    metaarray nestedarray {{
        {{ {"nestedfoo1",nullptr, 0},  {"nestedbaz1", nullptr, 1}  }},
        {{ {"nestedfoo2",nullptr, 10}, {"nestedbaz2", nullptr, 11} }}
    }};
```

Now you can pass the array by reference e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/d3h861d3v

Comment: It would be really difficult to have an array of `meta` inside `meta` struct.

Comment: @n.m. I am not quite sure I get what you mean here - you can just have a pointer to the metaarray (`metaarray *p {nullptr};`) instead of a pointer-to-point. I.e. I am suggesting using references (or pointers) to an STL - this would be easier to manage then c-style arrays IMO.